# ajax auto update table with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

hello and right at the beginning, I still have not much experience with js or jquery but I am still working on my skills.

I have a table and the data in the table are coming from an external json file, to which I have no influence.

creating the table works fine, but the next step is to refresh the data in the table every "x" seconds.

I have done some research but i could not find any solutin till now.

the table it self:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Sign</th>
        <!--<th>Group</th>-->
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>On position</th>
        <th>Ignition on</th>
        <th>Moving</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="vehicleList">

</tbody>
</table>
```

the code, which creates the table is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
refreshTable();
$.getJSON(getshowObjectReportExtern, function(data){
    var vehicleListData = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        vehicleListData += '<tr id="rowVehicleStatus" class="">';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectno+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectname+'</td>';
        //vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectgroupname+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.postext_short+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.latitude_mdeg+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.longitude_mdeg+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.pos_time+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.ignition+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.standstill+'</td>';
        vehicleListData += '</tr>';     
    });
    $('#vehicleList').append(vehicleListData);


});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#vehicleList').load(getshowObjectReportExtern, function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });

});
```

the result at the moment is, that the table will be created but after the first reload the raw json data will be added to the table.

has anybody any advice for me?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` does, as the name suggestes, wait a period of time before executing. `setInterval` however creates a interval caller that is ran every `n` seconds. You have to change your signature method to that.

However, you have another function. Because you don't remove the previous dynamically added entries from the table before you append, you will append the same rows every time the interval runs. To avoid this, you should assign some class to the `tbody` or something of your table, then clear this before adding the content back. This ensures that the content of the `json` file is not added multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fetch the initial table
    refreshTable();

    // Fetch every 5 seconds
    setInterval(refreshTable, 5000);
});

function refreshTable(){
    $.getJSON(getshowObjectReportExtern, function(data) {
        var vehicleListData = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            vehicleListData += '<tr id="rowVehicleStatus" class="">';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectno+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectname+'</td>';
            //vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.objectgroupname+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.postext_short+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.latitude_mdeg+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.longitude_mdeg+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.pos_time+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.ignition+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '<td>'+value.standstill+'</td>';
            vehicleListData += '</tr>';     
        });

        // We use .html instead of .append here, to make sure we don't add the same
        // entries when the interval is ran for the n-th time.
        $('#vehicleList').html(vehicleListData);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.
I  understand but know I have to wait `n` seconds before the first time the data is loaded in the table and then the table header and the css class is removed.

Comment: stupid me. the table header will not be deleted any more.
`id="vehicleList"` was i the wrong row.

Comment: 50% is solved.
my current problem is, that I have no idea how to do an inital load of the data in the table and after that to start the refresh every `n` seconds.

Comment: @wuk986 It is in my code? When the document is ready it starts fetching the table every 5 seconds. If you want to fetch it before the 5 first seconds, just call `refreshTable` before setting the interval. See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh your table for every x seconds, you should use `setInterval()` function instead.